# CloudKit public database not working unless I login to iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

I'm trying to read data from the public database using CloudKit.

```
let publicDB = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
let query = ...
publicDB.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
    // "Internal Error" (1/1000); "Received a didCompleteWithError without receiving a response from the server">)
}
```

However, once I login to iCloud, I get the data back as expected.
Per the documentation, one should be able to access Public DB related records without being logged in, correct?

One thing to note, is that I am using the simulator.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 14):

Looks like I missed this part of the documentation:

> In development, when you run your app through Xcode on iOS Simulator
>   or an iOS device, you also need to enter iCloud credentials to read
>   records in the public database.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords.html)